# Display number of processes running every minute

Tags: linux, unix

I know to find the number of processes running is using ps aux

I'm not sure how I would make it repeat and refresh the search every minute

Answer (score 3):

```
while true
do
  any command
  sleep 1
od

watch -n 1 any command
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `top` command, which keeps on running, till you type `q` for quit. The second line of output gives the number of processes. The output is updated every 1.5 seconds. The periodicity of update of output can be changed via an argument to the `top` command.

Answer (score 0):

Set a cron job to run top in batch mode for one iteration